# Spacing paragraphs to line up double colon - dealing with white Space

Tags: html, whitespace, paragraph

I want my html to look like the same on screen, but it doesn't seem to space out the content correctly.

HTML:

```
            <p>Unit         :       Apartment 15</p>
            <p>Available    :       July 1, 2014</p>
            <p>Rent         :       $695</p>
```

This is how it looks on scren:

```
Size     : 1 Bedroom
Location     :   3343 Westerwald Street
Unit     : Apartment 15
Available: July 1, 2014
Rent: $695
```

Comment: The HTML itself doesn't really look like that. Could you post your CSS code and maybe screenshot(s)?

Comment: `I want my CSS to look like my CSS` that's an absurd.

Comment: Use table. Simplest way.

Comment: @zishe oops... my eyes are starting to shut, I fixed the original post.

Comment: you can use `&nbsp` for spaces... i wouldn't do that anyways... :/

Comment: The code posted does *not* produce such a look. SO plays tricks on your markup and has changed some spaces to tabs.

Comment: Where do you have *double* colon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the simple way to achieve this output:

Html:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>test1</td><td>:</td><td>test1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test2</td><td>:</td><td>tesxt2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test3</td><td>:</td><td>test2</td></tr>
</table>
```

Css:

```
td{width:100px}
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u6t5h/)

Output:

```
test1   :   test1
test2   :   tesxt2
test3   :   test2
```

Comment: use of table is now discouraged

Comment: @user3127499, use of tables is discouraged only by people who have misunderstood the opinion “don’t use tables for layout”.

Comment: The illogical part here is the use of a column for the colons, which are not part of the tabular data but punctuation between data items.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to have the content rendered as-is to set `white-space: pre` on the `p` elements. As a side effect, this makes the font monospaced and reduced in size.

However, such an approach reduces accessibility, and it is not possible to change the font to non-monospace without breaking the layout.

A better approach is to use an HTML table. It depends on the details of the desired visual appearance how you do this. The use of colons is somewhat unusual here. It normally suffices to have the data in columns. But if you really want the colons, you can use e.g. this (where the colons are not part of the data itself but CSS generated content):

```
<style>
th, td { 
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: normal;
}
td:before {
  content: ":";
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 2em;
}
</style>
<table>
<tr><th>Unit <td>Apartment 15
<tr><th>Available <td>July 1, 2014
<tr><th>Rent <td>$695
</table>
```

Comment: I just learned you can use white-space:pre-wrap   this will still honor linebreaks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any CSS just use this:

```
<p>Unit&nbsp;:&nbsp;Apartment 15</p>
<p>Available&nbsp;:&nbsp;July 1, 2014</p>
<p>Rent&nbsp;:&nbsp;$695</p>
```

Here `&nbsp;` is non breaking space. And doesn't matter if you give actual space breaks in html, they don't show up.

And using the above isn't the best way, but if you don't want any css it works. You'd be better off looking into positioning or using table elements! Cheers!

Comment: Thank you. I won't be using this, but it's something I didn't know!